# How many 5-lists taken from [10] have no pair of adjacent elements equal?

Tags: combinatorics

I have come across this question that states "How many 5 lists taken from $[10]$ have no pair of adjacent elements equal" So $8773$ would not be allowed but $8783$ would be allowed. My thought was that if we have to fill $5$ positions the first position could be any of the $10$ digits available and the next $4$ would have only $9$ options each. Leading me to believe the answer would be:
$$10\cdot9\cdot9\cdot9\cdot9=65610$$

Am I missing something here, or is this an appropriate way of thinking about a question like this. Any confirmation or assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is entirely correct. Choosing the elements one by one, each element is only restricted by the previous element, which leads to your answer.